# EC2 ubuntu server storage memory consumption increasing day by day

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, storage

I have an EC2 ubuntu `t2.micro` server and running a Node.js app with MongoDB database which is also installed in same server. I'm observing that the storage memory consumption is increasing day by day. I'm trying to find out the reason but I'm not seeing any process of file which is causing.

I have installed **Nginx** and **PM2** and tried to turn off it logs as well but no luck.

The output of `df -h`

[image]

The output of `sudo du -sh /*`
[image]

Can someone please help me to figure out if any hidden process is utilizing the storage?

Thanks

Comment: What does `sudo lsof | egrep "deleted|COMMAND"` show ?

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward you saved me. when I ran this command it was showing many mongodb & nginx log files which were actually deleted but not completely and they were consuming storage in the disk. I just killed those processes and now its showing the right storage consumption.